# announceforaccessibility is not working

Tags: android, accessibility

i'm trying to develop an application for visually impaired people, i'm using accessibility for sure
i'm trying to set a welcome for the user without the user touching anything that should be played only in accessibility mode and when the activity launches 
i have a `Textview` that welcomes the user and i have set the message in the `contentDescription` of it
and `onCreate` method i call

```
textView.announceForAccessibility("Welcome");
```

i've also tried

```
textView.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED);
textView.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED);
textView.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_ANNOUNCEMENT);
```

and almost every `AccessibilityEvent type` none of them works
i'm testing on nexus6p with android v7 also with accessibility enabled

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22046941/send-accessibility-event-not-linked-to-view) earlier i ave found the answer 
all i did i added this snippet of code and it worked like charm

```
AccessibilityManager manager = (AccessibilityManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);
if (manager.isEnabled()) {
    AccessibilityEvent e = AccessibilityEvent.obtain();
    e.setEventType(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_ANNOUNCEMENT);
    e.setClassName(getClass().getName());
    e.setPackageName(context.getPackageName());
    e.getText().add("some text");
    manager.sendAccessibilityEvent(e);
}
```

Comment: Agree with this answer. sometimes you may need to add a delay for the code.  val handler = Handler()
                        handler.postDelayed({ }, 1000)